# Retrieving an encrypted password in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sha1, password-encryption

The following code is what I've used to encrypt a password in PHP...

```
$password = sha1(sha1($_POST['password']).sha1("mySalt@$#(%"));
```

What code can I use so users can log in using what they typed?

Answer (score 3):

`sha1` is a hashing algorithm, not a 2-way encryption. You cannot retrieve the original password.

1. Hash the submitted password using the same algorithm.
2. Fetch, from your database, the password hash for the user in question.
3. Compare the two hashes. If they match, the credentials are OK.

---

- Don't use sha1 for password hashing, [it isn't safe enough](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash)
- [Use a unique salt per credential](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Use_a_cryptographically_strong_credential-specific_salt), don't reuse the same one each time.

Comment: thanks for your replies. my question is: which code do i use so users form my database can login into their accounts? this is just a small uni project by the way

Comment: Writing a complete authentication system is somewhat beyond the scope appropriate for a SO question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [crypt](http://php.net/crypt) for password hashing, sha1/md5 are too weak.

All you need:

```
function check_password($password) {  
    ...//get db password to compare
    if (crypt($post_password, $db_results[0]['password']) == $db_results[0]['password']) {  
        return true;  
    } else { return false; }
}
```